# how to enter different values in multiple textboxes through voice in C#

Tags: c#, voice-recognition, speech

I have need to write an application which uses a speech recognition engine.

How can I enter different values in multiple textboxes through voice in c#?

I can enter value in single textbox but not in second textbox. I have the following code for entering value in single textbox.

```
private SpeechRecognitionEngine rec;

private void voice()     
{
    rec = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    rec.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
    Choices choice = new Choices("apple","Orange","Onion");
    GrammarBuilder gr = new GrammarBuilder(choice);
    Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gr);
    rec.LoadGrammar(grammar);
    rec.SpeechRecognized += 
        new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(rec_SpeechRecogonized);
    rec.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
}

void rec_SpeechRecogonized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RecognizedWordUnit word in e.Result.Words)
    {
         textBox1.Text = word.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use certain recognised words as "commands" to "focus" a particular text box and then any other recognised text that follows is placed in that text box...

Answer (score 0):

I will do something like this (very simple example):

```
private SpeechRecognitionEngine rec;

private void voice()     
{
    rec = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    rec.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
    Choices choice = new Choices("apple","Orange","Onion", "next");
    GrammarBuilder gr = new GrammarBuilder(choice);
    Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gr);
    rec.LoadGrammar(grammar);
    rec.SpeechRecognized += 
        new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(rec_SpeechRecogonized);
    rec.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
}

private TextBox currentInput;
void rec_SpeechRecogonized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    if (currentInput == null) currentInput = textBox1;

    foreach (RecognizedWordUnit word in e.Result.Words)
    {
         if (word.Text = "next") { currentInput = textBox2; }
         else { currentInput.Text = word.Text; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Accept the answer and up your reputation score ;-)